Can you try to help diagnose why my chain is falling off of the large chainring?
My bike is a trek 1000, 2005 model Im pretty sure, not sure what is original or replaced on it.
The chain is falling out onto the cranks when on the outer chainring, can work for a bit but eventually happens, usually when pedalling harder.
The problem is I see many things that may be the cause and replacing everything would get costly. I think it is one specific thing causing the problem (though others will cause problems soon)
The whole drivetrain is dirty, yes, I need to address that but I doubt it is near bad enough to cause a chain to fall off... I will be buying chain cleaner and lube when I order whatever parts I need.
Chain looks a bit worn, some links are loose side-to-side?

Front derailleur with chain on smallest rear sprocket, despite the clearance shown I start getting chain rub in this max gear which isnt acceptable. It goes away if high limit is increased but the chain slipping gets even worse.

The chain sits kinda loose on the chainring, I dont know if this normal or not, maybe chain tension could be better?

One particularly bad tooth on chainring... I think the cause is probably the chainring at this point.


So, there are a number of wear components on bikes that may surprise people. Not all of them are cheaper to replace. It is cheaper to replace your chain more frequently, and I realize this may come as a surprise to some newer cyclists. Let's be clear about one thing: that bike has seen a lot of miles, and that is unquestionably a good thing. You should not be ashamed of the state of the bike.
Front derailleur adjustment - not the only problem
Normally, we'd check the outer limit screw for the front derailleur. It controls how far out the FD moves. It may be set a bit too far out.
Chainring wear
The big chainring is extremely worn. Normally, I think it would have been replaced before it got this worn. The small chainring also seems very worn. One of the tests for a worn chainring is trying to lift the chain off the ring - if you can easily do so, it's worn. The chainring teeth get shark-toothed when it goes beyond this stage. This is the stage you are at. So, those will need to be replaced.
The chain is probably worn
It's very likely the chain is worn. There are tools to check this at a bike shop. Cyclists should consider buying themselves a chain tool, like the Park CC-4, which is inexpensive. (If you have a SRAM AXS chain, I believe this tool won't measure accurately, but that definitely doesn't apply to the OP.)
Chains seem to stretch, because the pins and rollers wear. Chain wear tools detect this elongation - if you see a recommendation to replace your chain at .75% wear, this is what they're talking about.
Over time, chains also wear laterally. That is, they're floppier side to side, which you may be seeing. That's likely to affect shifting, and it could contribute to the problems you're experiencing.
Also, at this point, it's likely that the cassette is worn, and that the bike needs new cables and cable housing.
You're not the only cyclist who has let their bike go a bit too long without maintenance, but they do need maintenance
You may be worried about being judged if you go into a bike store. And yes, it's possible this will happen, since young men sometimes tend to do this. It's also possible - maybe even more likely - that they will be outright impressed at how long this bicycle has been in service. And they have likely seen this sort of case before (but, again, that bike is probably more used than they usually see, and if they are not impressed they ought to be).
This is likely to cost a bit, but that is a 2005 bike. It is now 2024. Since you are on older components, it's likely that cheaper third party chainrings and cassettes can be found. There may be cheaper chains than Shimano, but I'm not sure that they're much cheaper.
I would suggest getting on top of chain maintenance first! Here's one answer that gives you a few steps to go through. The better you maintain your chain, the slower it wears, and the slower the cassette and chainrings wear - that elongated chain will wear at the teeth.
OK, I am a very experienced cyclist, and I have what I'd describe as an heirloom bike from 2007. If I let my bike go this long without maintenance, I'd be a bit embarrassed. But I'm a very experienced cyclist, and this would be obvious to bike shop employees. You have no reason to be embarrassed, since we all understand that it takes time for people to learn how much maintenance bikes need. It's not a lot of maintenance, but they need some.

This was a used bike purchased recently, I noticed wear on initial inspection but during short test ride it shifted and pedalled smoothly enough, after putting some more km on it the issues started to manifest
Based on your advice, seems like the best (or only) option is to replace the whole drivetrain and hopefully have a bike that will work well for a long while.

@blofi The chain, both chainrings, the cassette, and the cables. I don't think this counts as the whole drivetrain. You may find it more cost-effective to replace the crankset, but see what's the shop tells you.

Also the rear derailleur pulley wheels but, yeah, still not quite the whole thing.
Im planning to remove the front derailleur and use a single narrow-wide chainring, I have always stuck to using just one of the chainrings on bikes.

Make sure the front deraileur is set up properly. Angle and high limit especially. Check for wobble in chainring & play in crank since you describe cage-rub(?) even with what sounds like a high-limit being set too wide.
The large chainring looks very worn, check for relative movement between chain/chainring by first backpedaling a bit and then applying torque to the pedals while keeping the bike still. If significant relative movement and/or slippage when applyin torque, then chain and/or chainring is worn which might be the root cause of the problem (chain slipping off teeth and then falling off to the outside?). The same test works for the cassette/chain. It is often usefull to compare with the small chainring or the least used cogs on the cassette.
If the large chainring is worn down, the cassette and chain is probably worn out as well (unless replaced more recently).
